# kendoDropDownList is not a function - Kendo UI For jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Cannot figure out why this error is happening. I am trying to create a kendoDropDownList on one of my pages. That page has a reference to jQuery, then a reference to kendo.all.min.js[image]

The kendo dataSource gets created fine but jQuery throws an error when trying to call .kendoDropDownList(...)[image]

590 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoDropDownList is not a function

This exact same code works on another page fine, so I'm not sure what is happening with this one.